# Is there a simpler way to link to the help?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many answers (and some questions) include information from vim's builtin documentation.  I often find myself on google looking for an HTML version of the vim help, so I can link to it in my answers.

With this in mind, I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to automatically link `:help [key]` in answers to online documentation, so the audience doesn't have to switch from their browser to vim to check it out?
2. Is there a preferred site hosting the vim documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/90/adding-in-links-to-vimdoc

Comment: I think it would be nicer if we could auto-link using Vim's help syntax, e.g. `|:buffers|`. Anything inside `|`'s would be treated as a help tag. Not requiring the `:help` keyword allows for more casual language.

Comment: Any syntax like `[help:topic]` would be nice, with a way to transform `\`:h [help::buffers]\`` into [`:h :buffers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abuffers). But to automate it the doc hosting site needs to be reliable, like [vimhelp](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/) probably is and [this one](https://neovim.io/doc/user/) that should be used for questions specific to Neovim. Maybe vi.SE could host some static files? :)

Answer (score 9):

**Update 20150825**: an improved  of this now lives at http://code.arp242.net/helplink.vim. It has a number of improvements, and you can install it as a plugin :-)

I will leave the original since it's a lot simpler and might be more helpful to show how this can be done.

---

I've been using this function; it will (backwards) look for the first tag, and return that in Markdown link. It also puts in the clipboard...

So you can just use `:help` from Vim, and when you want to link something use `:echo Helplink()`.

```
" Make help link (markdown format)
" TODO: Find all tags, and let the user choose which one to use
fun! Helplink()
    " Get the name of the tag, With help from:
    " https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/434/get-name-of-nearest-tag-to-the-cursor
    if !search('\*\zs[^*]\+\*$', 'bW')
        echoerr "No tag found"
    endif
    let l:line = getline('.')
    let l:start = col('.') - 1
    call search('\*', '', line('.'))
    let l:len =  col('.') - l:start - 1
    let l:tagname = strpart(l:line, l:start, l:len)

    " TODO: Also support Python 2 and maybe Ruby...
    let l:tagname_esc = system('python3 -c "import sys, urllib.parse as p;  empty=' . "''" . '; print(p.quote(sys.argv[1], safe=empty), end=empty)" ' . shellescape(b:tagname))
    let l:file = split(expand('%'), '/')[-1]
    let l:url = "http://vimhelp.appspot.com/" . l:file . ".html#" . l:tagname_esc
    let l:md = '[`:help ' . l:tagname . '`](' . l:url . ')'

    " Copy it to the clipboard
    let @+ = l:md

    return l:md
endfun
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to automatically link :help [key] in answers to
>   online documentation, so the audience doesn't have to switch from
>   their browser to vim to check it out?

Without commenting on whether or not I think such a feature would be useful, that kind of specialized feature generally wouldn't be written for a site until after it's out of beta. You may want to bring it up again if we get to that point.

> Is there a preferred site hosting the vim documentation?

Whichever you want to use is entirely up to you.

http://vimhelp.appspot.com/ seems okay.
There's also http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/ but this seems outdated (Vim 7.3)

Comment: vimhelp has spectacularly poor searching, because it uses Google, and vimdoc has pretty good searching, because it uses an index. So what I often do is search either on vim or vimdoc, and "tranlate" the result to vimhelp.

Comment: What does http://vimhelp.appspot.com/ have over http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/ ?

Comment: @Gilles The reason I prefer vimhelp is it's help for vim 7.4 (vimhelp) vs. 7.3 (vimdoc). Actually vimhelp says its 7.4.648, so almost 5 years newer.

Comment: I don't know, it's simply an option and happened to be the first one in my history list when I went looking for one.

Comment: @Gilles vimdoc.sourceforge.net is rather outdated; as home page page says: `For Vim version 7.3. Last change: 2010 Jul 2`...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker `vim --version | head -n 1` → `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 10 2013 02:27:59)` so vimdoc.sf.net looks appropriate to me. That way you don't risk recommending super-recent stuff that the asker may not have yet.

Comment: @Gilles And now you risk linking to documentation that doesn't describe feature *foo* that you present in your answer; in a few other cases it may even be wrong (such as the `cryptmethod` setting). Vim 7.4 is from Aug 2013, so it's not "super-recent". CentOS 5 (support until 2017) ships with Vim 7.0; IIRC CentOS 6 uses Vim 7.2 (support until 2020). Should we link to Vim 7.0 until 2017, and 7.2 until 2020? No one site can please everyone. Given that Vim is very backwards-compatible (perhaps even to a fault) linking to the most recent stable version seems like the best thing to do to me.