# Which questions led to the creation of a new plugin?

Tags: discussion

On occasion a question will inspire members to not just give *answer* to the question, but to go a step further and develop it in to a full-featured plugin.

Let's list all vi.SE inspired plugins here!

The format I've used for this is:

```
**[`plugin_name`]()** by [Author]() from [Question]().
```

---

Also see: [Mark questions that led to creating a new plugin](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1381/51).

Comment: Do questions on SO count as well?

Comment: @LucHermitte It seems I missed the notification on that comment, sorry 'bout that :-/ I would say no, since Stack Overflow is a different site.

Comment: You may have also missed my question on the other topic: "What about questions that initiated new features in pre-existing plugins? For instance, to answer vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/… , I've added a couple of functions and mappings to something that was already there."

Comment: @LucHermitte Not sure where that was posted, but if a question prompted significant expansion (i.e. more than a small bugfixe or trivial change) to an existing plugin then I'd say it's fine to add it to this list.

Comment: You mean my (second) comment? It was posted over there: http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1381/51. Otherwise, "trivial" is tough to define. In that [case](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/quick-search-limited-to-a-c-function), the change consists in 8 effective lines. And yet it relies on things already defined that were far from being trivial.

Comment: @LucHermitte Yeah, there's a grey area; use your judgement. I don't expect anyone will object adding particular plugin to the list.

Answer (score 18):

In alphabetical order:

**[`auto_mkdir2.vim`](https://arp242.net/code/auto_mkdir2.vim)** by [Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) from [How do I save a file in a directory that does not yet exist?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/678/51) and [How can I stop Vim from writing a file without throwing an error?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/695/51).

**[`colorscheme-changer.vim`](https://github.com/statox/colorscheme-changer.vim)** by [Adrien Fabre](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox) from [How can I set an option differently depending on time of day?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13660/1841).

**[`confirm_quit.vim`](https://arp242.net/code/confirm_quit.vim/)** by [Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) from [How do I avoid exiting vim to open a new file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3712/51)

**[`globedit.vim`](https://arp242.net/code/globedit.vim/)** by [Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) from [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2108/51).

**[`GOD.vim`](https://github.com/statox/GOD.vim)** by [Adrien Fabre](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox) from [How can I quickly convert a Vim help tag to a vimhelp.appspot.com link?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4346/1841).

**[`helplink.vim`](https://arp242.net/code/helplink.vim/)** by [Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) from [Is there a simpler way to link to the help?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1248/51)

**[`meta-map.vim`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/meta-map.vim)** by [Luc Hermitte](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/626/luc-hermitte) from [Use variable that depends on function for mapping inside vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/use-variable-that-depends-on-function-for-mapping-inside-vimrc)

**[`next-undisplayed-buffer.vim`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/next-undisplayed-buffer.vim)** by [Luc Hermitte](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/626/luc-hermitte) from [Can I cycle through buffers while skipping ones I've opened?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5643/can-i-cycle-through-buffers-while-skipping-ones-ive-opened)

**[`pushd.vim`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/pushd.vim)** by [Luc Hermitte](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/626/luc-hermitte) from [Is there a way to quickly navigate to previously visited directories](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27478/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-navigate-to-previously-visited-directories/27487#27487)

**[`relative-n.vim`](https://github.com/nobe4/relative-n.vim)** by [Victor Haffreingue](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1821/nobe4) from [Show only every n relative line number](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4299/1821)

**[`spellrotate.vim`](https://github.com/tweekmonster/spellrotate.vim)** by [Tommy Allen](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/5229/tommy-a) from [Command to loop through spelling suggestions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8692/7642).

**[`substitute_unless_string.vim`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/substitute_unless_string.vim)** by [Luc Hermitte](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/626/luc-hermitte) from [Search and replace, but ignore text in quotes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/search-and-replace-but-ignore-text-in-quotes)

**[`undofile_warn.vim`](https://arp242.net/code/undofile_warn.vim/)** by [Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) from [Can I be notified when I'm undoing changes from the undofile?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2115/51)

**[`vim-compare-lines`](https://github.com/statox/vim-compare-lines)** by [Adrien Fabre](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox) from  [XOR two lines to see differences](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7348/1841)

**[`vim-dialect`](https://github.com/danielbmarques/vim-dialect)** by [Daniel B. Marques](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/7642/danielbmarques) from [Make zG and zW persistent](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8768/7642).

**[`Vim-Operator-Insert-Append`](https://github.com/bagohart/vim-operator-insert-append)** by [bagohart](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/28743/bagohart), based on an answer by [Blasco](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/15345/blasco), from [Making operator insert and append repeatable](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21593/making-operator-insert-and-append-repeatable).

**[`vim-signjump`](https://github.com/ZeroKnight/vim-signjump)** by [ZeroKnight](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1452/zeroknight) from [Is there a way to quickly jump to signs?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15846/1452).